# Motion-daemon: /var/log/motion/motion.log permission denied

Tags: motion

I have installed the *motion* package on my pi (stretch). If I start *motion* in the foreground it's working but when I try to start it as a daemon it fails with the following log message:

```
motion: permission denied for /var/log/motion/motion.log
```

I've seen many approaches to fix this problem by tinkering with the permissions of /var/log/... but this does not convince me.

**Q** What's the correct way to fix this problem?

**Update**

I've *motion* installed as a service and I start it for testing with

```
sudo service motion start
```

but even then it fails with the error message below

> raspberrypi motion[323]: [0:motion] [ERR] [ALL] myfopen: Error opening file /var/log/motion/motion.log with mode a: Permission denied

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gotcha! For testing I started *motion* with `sudo motion -b`. Therefore, `/var/log/motion/motion.log` was written with `root:root`. After removing `/var/log/motion` and reboot, the motion-daemon was up and running and had the permission to write to the log.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I think this should be the accepted answer.

After removing the `/var/log/motion` directory, restart the service using `sudo service motion restart` and it works correctly.

Comment: Same thing happened to me.  Had to
sudo rm -fr /var/log/motion
then restart the service and now the right owner/group shows on that folder.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The directory doesn't get created after a reboot and I get the same error with after `sudo service motion restart`

Comment: @NickG You need to remove `/var/log/motion` (i.e. `sudo rm -r /var/log/motion`) at first and then reboot.

Answer (score 8):

There are three ways to fix the problem.  All are really the same, just from different angles. That is to make sure that the user starting motion has the access permission to write into the /var/log/motion/ directory. First could just make that user the owner of the directory. And give the owner write access.  The second would be start the daemon using root by using the sudo command.  An alternative third method is to allow write access to the log directory for a group 'motion' and to make that a supplementary group of any user needing to be able to start the daemon.

E.g.  Assuming you want to create group motion and add user pi

`pi@raspberrypi:~$sudo groupadd motion
  pi@raspberrypi:~$sudo usermod -aG motion pi`

Finally change the ownership and permission of the /var/log/motion directory

`pi@raspberrypi:~$cd /var/log
 pi@raspberrypi:/var/log $ chown root:motion motion
 pi@raspberrypi:/var/log $ chmod 664 motion`

It is simpler and more normal to start the daemon as the root user who should already have all the correct permissions by using sudo command as I already mentioned.

Comment: How do I know which user is running motion? (newby here)

Answer (score 4):

I have tested all answers but no solution. After I reboot the raspberry pi, problem still there. Follow the procedure below to fix the problem.

---

Create another directory:

```
sudo mkdir /home/log/motion
```

Create a log file in this directory:

```
sudo touch /home/log/motion/motion.log
```

Change the config file as this new log file:

```
 nano /etc/motion/motion.conf
```

Add/change this line:

```
logfile /home/log/motion/motion.log
```

The important part is adding `motion` user permission to our new log file because it will run as `motion:motion`:

```
sudo chown motion:motion /home/log/motion/motion.log
```

Comment: Thank you! I've read so many answers and this is the first one that addresses the fact that motion runs as the motion user.

Comment: `/home/log`- wouldn't that mean that the username is `log`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller My user was `log` on this example.

Answer (score 2):

I made mistake and opened 2 sessions of Motion:
1. Was autostarted with Raspbian
2. Was initiated by me `sudo motion`

This initiated by me blocked file, `sudo rm -rf /var/log/motion/*` helped me.

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?

Comment: If you can't see ill explain you. If somebody will asking google with "sudo motion" he will find this answer. I explained one of cases.

Answer (score 0):

As of Raspian Stretch (4.19.27-v7+ #1206) and motion 3.2.12, this also worked:

1. created a new directory (`sudo mkdir /tmp/motion`)
2. change permissions (`sudo chown motion:motion /tmp/motion`)
3. change `logfile` in `/etc/motion/motion.conf` to point to `/tmp/motion` (`sudo nano /etc/motion/motion.conf` and add `logfile /tmp/motion`)
4. restart motion (sudo service motion restart).

Comment: The OP told you (albeit in a veiled way) that he/she is using Raspbian Stretch. So how is an answer about Motion on Ubuntu in any way relevant to that?

Comment: Dougie ...Thanks  ...a tired mind slips easily.